# vuelidate, как сделать custom проверку?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate, validate

Мне нужно с помощью vuelidate сделать проверку, начинается ли строка с цифры 7? В доках нашел что-то типо того:

```
phone: {
required,
minLength: minLength(11),
maxLength: maxLength(11),
isPhone(phone) {
if (phone[0] === '7') {
    return true;
}
},
```

},

но при использовании  `v-if="!$v.form.phone.isPhone"` вылетает ошибка: `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '__isVuelidateAsyncVm' of undefined"`. Кто занет как правильно сделать. И еще, если знаете как проверить есть ли вообще ошибки в валидации(во всей форме), то как это можно проверить, что бы делать disabled кнопки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В доках есть пример https://vuelidate.js.org/#custom-validators

Есть еще неплохой пример тут https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/08/27/vue-js-form-handling-vuelidate/

Следует создать отдельный файл validators.js, где будут размещаться кастомные функции для валидации, пример содержания файла:

```
export function isPhone(phone) {
    return phone[0] === '7' 
}
```

Потом этот файл подключить в компоненте:

```
import { isPhone } from "./validators";
```

А дальше уже использовать этот кастомный валидатор так же как встроенные.

> И еще, если знаете как проверить есть ли вообще ошибки в валидации(во всей форме), то как это можно проверить, что бы делать disabled кнопки?

Можно использовать такую проверку, более подробно есть в доках в разделе Data nesting:

```
this.$v.$invalid
```